# Can I get the same firebase data on two seperate view controllers?

Tags: swift, firebase

I’m using firebase as my backend.

I can get data put in perfectly how I want it, and call it back in view controller a.

However, when I put the same exact code in view controller b nothing happens.

What other steps would you have to do? Do you have to have a seperarte input for VC B? Or can I use the same data?

Comment: Yes you can pass data between viewcontrollers. Search for 'Pass data between viewcontroller Swift' on google or here.

Comment: In this case scenario I agree with J.Doe...depending on the data it seems more efficient to pass the data between viewcontrollers. But, in general when I hear "... I put the same exact code in..." --that is usually not the case, or at least it is called differently. But without seeing your code it is all speculation.

Comment: The question is far to broad. Why would want to have the exact same code in two controllers? What is the relationship between them... master/slave? Subview? What does 'nothing happens' mean? Did you forget to instantiate the second controller? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data between view controllers, but maybe you prefere to make an own class that receives data from the server and instantiate it in the view controllers. I personally want to prevent to instantiate view controllers too often.

Answer (score 0):

You can Make super -> Child classes relation, I have used carbonKit which sets multiple viewcontroller Keep your data in super or main class and use it with superObj.